# WPF Updating DataBinding

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, data-binding

So, I tested many answers I found on different topics, but still my WPF app does not update binded data. When I set all Properties before Initializing MainWindow Data are displayed correctly, but I need to select directory, date, etc. before loading the data. Tried to change DataContext in code behind, but IT doesn't work. All the classes used as VieModels have implemented INotifyPropertyChanged interface (but the PropertyChanged values is always null). I'm out of ideas now...

This is XAML code:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfDataBinding.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfDataBinding"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="600" Width="800" Name="Logs">
    <Window.DataContext>
        <local:CustomDataContexts />
    </Window.DataContext>
    <Grid Name="Logi">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <local:CustomButton Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="1" Margin="5" Height="35" Width="100" x:Name="Choose" Text="Wybierz:" ImageSource="Resources/choose.png" Click="CustomButton_Click" />
        <local:CustomButton Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="2" Margin="5" Height="35" Width="100" x:Name="Load" Text="Załaduj:" ImageSource="Resources/load.png" Click="CustomButton_Click" />
        <local:CustomButton Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="3" Margin="5" Height="35" Width="100" x:Name="Search" Text="Szukaj:" ImageSource="Resources/search.png" Click="CustomButton_Click" />
        <local:CustomButton Grid.Column="3" Grid.Row="2" Margin="5" Height="80" Width="100" x:Name="Next" Grid.RowSpan="2" Text="Dalej:" ImageSource="Resources/next.png" Click="CustomButton_Click" />
        <TabControl DataContext="{Binding TextViewModel}" x:Name="tabControl" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" ItemsSource="{Binding TxtView.Tabs, ElementName=Logs, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, Mode=TwoWay}">
            <TabControl.ItemTemplate>
                <!-- this is the header template-->
                <DataTemplate>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Header}" />
                </DataTemplate>
            </TabControl.ItemTemplate>
            <TabControl.ContentTemplate >
                <!-- this is the body of the TabItem template-->
                <DataTemplate>
                    <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding EntryViewModels}">
                        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Entry.Tag}"/>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
                    </ListView>
                </DataTemplate>
            </TabControl.ContentTemplate>
        </TabControl>
        <TabControl DataContext="{Binding SingleNode}" x:Name="tabControl2" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="2"  Grid.ColumnSpan="2" ItemsSource="{Binding Tabs}">
            <TabControl.ItemTemplate>
                <!-- this is the header template-->
                <DataTemplate>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Header}" />
                </DataTemplate>
            </TabControl.ItemTemplate>
            <TabControl.ContentTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Content}" />
                </DataTemplate>
            </TabControl.ContentTemplate>
        </TabControl>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Code-behind looks like this:

```
    public CustomDataContexts DataContexts { get; set; }
    public string Path { get; set; }
    public Files Files { get; set; }

    public MainWindow()
    {
        /*Path = @"C:\Users\Slawek\Desktop\Logs\logi";
        Files = new Files(Path);
        Files.NarrowFiles(false, DateTime.MinValue);
        var entry = new EntryCollection(Files.SelectedFiles[1], Files.SelectedFiles, null);
        TxtView = new TxtViewModel(new List<TxtTabItem>(new[] { new TxtTabItem(entry) }));*/
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void CustomButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        var fe = (FrameworkElement) sender;
        switch (fe.Name)
        {
            case "Choose":
                var g = new FolderBrowserDialog();
                if (g.ShowDialog() == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK)
                    Path = g.SelectedPath;
                break;
            case "Load":
                DataContexts = new CustomDataContexts();
                Files = new Files(Path);
                Files.NarrowFiles(false, DateTime.MinValue);
                var entry = new EntryCollection(Files.SelectedFiles[1], Files.SelectedFiles, null);
                DataContexts.TextViewModel = new TxtViewModel(new List<TxtTabItem>(new[] { new TxtTabItem(entry) }));
                break;
            case "Search":
                break;
            case "Next":
                break;
        }
    }
```

CustomDataContexts class:

```
public class CustomDataContexts : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private TxtViewModel textViewModel;
    public XmlViewModel SingleNode { get; set; }

    public TxtViewModel TextViewModel
    {
        get { return textViewModel; }
        set { OnPropertyChanged("TextViewModel"); }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;
        if (handler != null) handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}
```

EntryViewModel:

```
public class EntryViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private SingleEntry entry;

    public SingleEntry Entry
    {
        get { return entry; }
        set 
        {
            entry = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("Entry");
        }
    }

    public EntryViewModel(SingleEntry entry)
    {
        Entry = entry;
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;
        if (handler != null) handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}
```

TxtViewModel:

```
public class TxtViewModel :INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private ObservableCollection <TxtTabItem> tabs;

    public ObservableCollection<TxtTabItem> Tabs
    {
        get { return tabs; }
        set
        { 
            tabs = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("Tabs");
        }
    }

    public TxtViewModel(List<TxtTabItem> items)
    {
        Tabs = new ObservableCollection <TxtTabItem>();
        foreach (var txtTabItem in items)
        {
            Tabs.Add(txtTabItem);
        }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;
        if (handler != null) handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}
```

And finally TxtTabItem class:

```
public class TxtTabItem : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public string Header { get; set; }
    public ObservableCollection<EntryViewModel> EntryViewModels { get; set; }

    public TxtTabItem(EntryCollection collection)
    {
        Header = collection.Date.ToShortDateString();
        EntryViewModels = new ObservableCollection <EntryViewModel>();
        foreach (var entry in collection.Entries)
        {
            EntryViewModels.Add(new EntryViewModel(entry));
        }
        OnPropertyChanged("EntryViewModels");
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    private void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;
        if (handler != null) handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}
```

I will be very grateful for any suggestions of how to make this code work. I'm pretty new to WPF and still don't know it well enough.

Comment: You're missing definitions of Files, and CustomButtons. Please create a fresh project and make sure it compiles, and add what's missing. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The framework is there, but generally to intialize controls to changes one binds to the `ItemsSource` property instead of directly to the DataContext.

In general the DataContext is something that provides information about the current item, but when it is null the parent's data context is used up until the page's data context.

The reason for that is a data context will hold a large class of properties and the binding will look (*reflect*/reflection) at the DataContext for that named property. So by using an `ItemsSource` one can bind to a specific set of items, while still having a `DataContext` full of information to allow other items on the control to be bound to *other* specific properties.

Under MVVM where the `VM` or view model is that class of properties as mentioned, set the page's data context to that VM and then bind to individual properties on the different controls you have *from the page's datacontext*.

so

```
  <TabControl DataContext="{Binding TextViewModel}" x:Name="tabControl"
```

becomes

```
  <TabControl ItemsSource="{Binding TextViewModel}" x:Name="tabControl"
```

once you set the page's data context to `TxtViewModel`.

---

I provide a binding/VM example on my blog article [Xaml: ViewModel Main Page Instantiation and Loading Strategy for Easier Binding](http://omegacoder.com/?p=1017).